# Can an DbContext with schema Bar, inherit from a DbContext with schema Foo, and reference Foo elements?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a `FooDbContext` inheriting from `BarContext`.

In `BarContext`, with Schema `Bar`, I have an object `Bar`.

In `FooDbContext`, with Schema `Foo`, I have an object `Foo`, which has an `BarFK` and `Bar` Navigation property.

In `BarDbContext`'s `OnModelCreation` method I've defined Bar:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  // define Foo...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>...etch...
}
```

And In `FooDbContext`'s `OnModelCreation` method, I've defined Foo and `Ignored` the "inherited" `Bar` entity:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  // define Foo...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>...etch...
  // Then ignore Bar
    modelBuilder.Ignore(Bar);
}
```

I've seeded it with a record to check and run *Migrations*.

It *nearly* works. In that it doesn't complain.

The BarFK value is filled as per the seeding -- but when I perform the query with `.Include(x=>x.Bar)` it complains that type Bar is not part of the model.

I'm not 100% sure, but pretty sure it would work if they both had the *same* Schema.

But it's hugely important to this app that I can keep the schema's distinct if at all possible.

*Is* it possible? If so....how?!?

Thanks!

Comment: Schema (as soon as this is not Oracle database) doesn't matter. You can't reference/load entity which is ignored (`Ignore` means "hey, this class is not an entity, don't do anything with it"). Keeping distinct schemas is ok, but separate db contexts containing linked entities mapped to *one and the same* database doesn't sound good to me.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I'm trying to follow the examples in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197754/entity-framework-one-database-multiple-dbcontexts-is-this-a-bad-idea/12625918#12625918 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969861/entity-framework-sharing-entities-across-different-dbcontexts ...I agree Ignore sounds like it wouldn't work, but those articles I *think* were saying it could work if ignored (it was a bit sketchy).